# Site loads normally, but PageSpeed thinks it takes minutes to do so

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am working on the site www.hatsfromoz.com.au
It appears to load OK (not very fast site, but loads in 5-6s at the moment).

However, Google PageSpeed thinks it takes 80-90s to get first data! 
Generating of the PageSpeed report takes about 20s, so how is it possible PageSpeed thinks it takes 80-90s?

I tried to load sites from different locations/countries and can not see huge delays.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rudolf

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You answer, while maybe be relevant to the topic, does not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Google measures various criteria, including "render-blocking resources" 
which take in your case about 74.98s according to the measurement:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=www.hatsfromoz.com.au

The site is hosted near Sydney (response times from Europe and US are over >160ms), maybe a service like CloudFlare or an CDN would be an option for you.

Test from Sydney, Australia: 
https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190601_28_ecb3147f22d762972b4cecb5cb7d6219/

Test from: Zurich, Switzerland: 
https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190601_YW_4f90dd07fd8c8a6229055b8167cf1850/

(I can't reach your site from Switzerland at the moment and have to use a VPN)